# Is there a word for an atomic unit of flour?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

Is there a word for an atomic unit of flour? If so, what is it?

I use *atomic unit* not to refer to chemical compound, molecule, or atom, but rather the individual particle of flour after milling. In the same way that grains of sand can be different sizes, I'm aware flour can also be different sizes, but I am trying to distinguish from a *clump* of flour, which is not a byproduct of milling, but adhesion.

Grain does not seem correct, as flour is composed of particles of a grain, with grain being a unit of corn, wheat, etc. However, if there is justification as to why it is actually the most correct, that is fine.

For instance, if the word was *foo*,

> "There are a few *foos* of flour on the counter."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46673/discussion-on-question-by-keozon-is-there-a-word-for-an-atomic-unit-of-flour).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a mote of flour?

From the American Heritage Dictionary:

> mote (n) A very small particle; speck.

Answer (score 40):

***[Specks](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/speck) of flour***:

> - a very little bit ***or particle:***
>
>   - We haven't a speck of sugar.

Dictionary.com

From: [Great British Bake Off](https://books.google.it/books?id=JFIbo6TIxVUC&pg=PT303&dq=%22specks%20of%20flour%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhkLTM1svPAhWHVhoKHTxFDJUQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=%22specks%20of%20flour%22&f=false):,

> - Lift the rest of the flour into the bowl and continue folding in ***until you no longer see streaks or specks of flour.*** Transfer the mixture to...

Comment: While I think that "specks of flour" sounds more natural than "particle", I would argue that a "speck of flour" would normally be considered a visible portion of flour, not an "atomic unit of flour". An "atomic unit of flour" could easily be intended to reference size which is smaller than visible, which a "speck" would normally not be used to describe. This ambiguity appears more a failing on the part of the question to be not sufficiently specific as to what is desired.

Answer (score 21):

As mentioned in your question itself, you may call it a ***particle*** of flour.

> "There are a few ***particles*** of flour on the counter."

M-W:

> **[particle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/particle)**
>   *noun*
>   **1 a** :  a minute quantity or fragment
>   **b** :  a relatively small or the **smallest discrete portion** or amount of something

Usage example: [Google search of "particles of flour"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22particles%20of%20flour%22&rct=j)

Comment: I see that you beat me to the punch. :-) I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @RichardKayser, I noticed it too; quite amusing how it repeated so soon :)

Comment: Indeed. We're tied 1-1. My answer was fine, but yours was better, i.e., your definition 1b and your link to your google search.

Comment: My immediate response began "particle", "speck" , "grain", and "granule", but before I went hunting for definitions, I checked the answers and comments... Humbug.

Answer (score 0):

The objection to using 'grain' to refer to a particle of flour is that the word 'grain' has several meanings among which are the specialised meaning of "a variety of cereal" (wheat, rye, oats, rice etc) and the more general meaning of "particle" (as in grains of salt, grains of sand and grains of powder).

I had great difficulty finding any reference to a name for particles of flour anywhere on the internet but I eventually found a section of [this site](http://www.recipetips.com/kitchen-tips/t--1026/types-of-wheat-flour.asp) which mentioned it. As can be seen in the extract below at least some people use the term 'grain' to refer to particles of flour (as I do). I appreciate that this is not definitive but, in the absence of anything better, it is an indication of a possible answer.

*Whole-Wheat Flour*

*Whole-wheat flour is produced from grinding the full wheat berry (kernel). All parts of the wheat berry are used in the flour including the bran, germ, and the endosperm, which when milled, creates the speckled brown color that is characteristic of the flour. Three granulations (particle size) of whole-wheat are produced: fine, medium, and coarse. The particle size influences the rate liquid is absorbed into the flour. **Finer grained flour absorbs liquid at a faster rate than medium or coarse grains**, thus affecting the preparation of the dough.*

***Fine grain whole-wheat flour** is used for all types of baked goods, such as breads, rolls, and pastries. **Medium grained** can be used for the same types of foods, but will provide a coarser crumb.*

Answer (score -5):

> Grain, noun
>
> > (uncountable) The harvested seeds of various grass food crops eg: wheat, corn, barley.
>
> Granule, Noun
>
> > (countable) A tiny grain, a small particle.

Source: http://the-difference-between.com/granule/grain

Edited due to popular opinion.

Comment: A *mol* is 6.022 x 10^23 particles.  That's a lot.

Comment: The *[mole](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit))* (note spelling) is a significant number of atomic units of a given substance; by definition it cannot be the atomic unit of something.

Comment: @Nij - *Mol* is an alternative spelling of *mole*, in the Avogadro sense.

Comment: Flour is a very complex mixture of organic compounds, with a high proportion of starch, which is a polymer (for which measuring in moles seems kind of pointless). How did you come up with the idea that it's C₄H₈O₄, and only that?!

Comment: @Rhymoid An additional oddity--why does " (flour)" not affect that site's search-bar behavior? "C4H8O4 (fizzbuzz)" doesn't work.

Comment: I actually like "granule" for this.  Remove the nonsense about Moles and this would be worth an upvote.  (If you quote some of the definition of granule that you link to, to show why it's a good word).